# Is it correct to say "X caught up on Y's feelings?"

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Example sentence:

> He seemed to have caught up on my distress, because he said, "I'm sorry."

I'm not very sure about this usage, because I tried to find something similar on Google but only found [this](https://www.google.com.tw/search?ei=OCO2W4LqOsXW8QWHzIn4Dw&q=%22%20caught%20up%20on%20my%20distress%22&oq=%22%20caught%20up%20on%20my%20distress%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...66659.69392.0.69542.9.9.0.0.0.0.131.624.7j2.9.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.3.141...0j0i7i30k1j0i30k1j0i8i7i30k1j0i8i7i10i30k1.0.TzkYCUmk79s).

Comment: Try a good [dictionary lookup site](https://www.onelook.com/?w=caught+up&ls=a).

Answer (score 2):

No. We **catch *on* to** such things.

> She gave him a few hints but, obtuse as always, he didn't catch on.